# systemctl suspend not working as expected

Tags: centos, systemd, suspend, systemctl

I am currently running CentOS 7.2 on a Lenovo ThinkPad, I have been having some weird issue lately, where the machine seemingly wakes up while closed, and in my laptop bag.

I am trying to manually issue the sleep command

```
systemctl suspend
```

However, it is not working as expected.

*The machine will go to sleep, and for some unknown reason, wake back up about 10 seconds later.*

I am running on battery, and there are no peripherals plugged in. I have also tried disabling the trackpad, with no avail. Thoughts / debugging steps?

> Linux my.machine.name 3.10.0-327.18.2.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu May 12 11:03:55 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: Migration request to serverfault.

Comment: CentOS on a _laptop_ doesn't automatically make it a serverfault question... Have you checked dmesg for suspend-related messages?